Why is this a wrong use of the product rule (for combinatorics) for finding number of onto functions?
I know the standard formula for finding the number of onto functions (for a function $f: [n] \to [m],$ where $[n] = \{1, ..., n\}$ and $n \ge m$) is the one that involves inclusion/exclusion, but I'm not fully sure why using the multiplication rule would be wrong here.
In particular, I did $${n\choose m} \cdot m! \cdot m^{n-m}$$
My reason is as follows:
${n\choose m} \cdot m!$ (Part 1): When I first did this part, I was just attempting to ensure that there are a set of elements in the domain that map to all the elements in the codomain, hence ensuring it's onto. However, I think a better way to justify my reasoning (that I just thought of while writing this question) is the intuition that for any onto function there must be a partial function that's bijective (not sure how to formally prove it though), hence this is what this part of my formula attempts to do.
$m^{n - m}$ (Part 2): This is just mapping the remaining domain elements to any of the elements in the codomain since we've already ensured the function is onto but still need these elements to map to exactly 1 element in the codomain to still be a function
I can see that there's at least one example where this overcounts:
f: [8] -> [4]

Part 1: choose the domain elements 1, 2, 3, 4 and map them to 1, 2,
3, 4 (respectively)
Part 2: map the remaining domain elements 5, 6,
7, 8 to 1, 2, 3, 4 (also respectively)

or

Part 1: choose the domain elements 5, 6, 7, 8 and map them to 1, 2,
3, 4 (respectively)
Part 2: map the remaining domain elements 1, 2,
3, 4 to 1, 2, 3, 4 (also respectively)

Both lead to the same function.
I think this hits home at a fundamental issue I often struggle with when using the multiplication rule, that is I don't know when to properly use it such that I avoid overcounting. What are the exact conditions in which you're allowed to use the product rule, since textbooks I feel don't give a rigorous enough definition and it leads to such errors for many people. Maybe I'm personally missing something here. Kindly please do help here.
Also, is there a way to modify my formula so that it can work?

At the very least, you are wildly overcounting. The unique function $f\colon{1,2}\to{1}$ is counted twice: once when you choose $1$ to be the element mapping to $1$ before deciding what $2$ does, and again when you first choose $2$ as the element mapping to $1$ before deciding what happens to $1$.

You are counting some onto functions twice.

For example, when $n=m+1,$ and given an onto function $f:[n]\to [m]$ there will be one pair if distinct values $i,j\in[n]$ such that $f(i)=f(j).$ So if $S_k=[n]\setminus{k}$ then $S_i$ and $S_j$ are two different subsets of size $m$ such that $f(S)=[m].$ So you have counted every function twice, and you have ended up with double the corrrect result. For bigger $n,$ you overcount different functions different numbers. So you can't just scale your result in the general case.

Thanks for the answers guys. I actually just edited the question to ask my real/main question, which is what are the exact conditions in which one can use the multiplication rule of combinatorics correctly. This particular problem was really just supposed to be an example of how one can use the multiplication rule wrong. I think many other people make similar mistakes too now that I see similar/same questions asked on this platform, where they use the exact same thought process! https://math.stackexchange.com/q/521299/801877

As a rule, don't completely rewrite your question to mean something else after someone has posted a long answer based on your first question. Ask a new question, instead.

As a rule, you should always ask "your real question", and not something else only to later rewrite your question so that it now asks the "real" one..

@ArturoMagidin I truly apologize for the impromptu change of question. I was just trying to think deeply about the question and hence attempted to steer the discussion in what I thought was the right direction, namely what are the specific/exact instances when the multiplication rule can be used, using this particular problem as a good example of how it can be used incorrectly, especially since other people have done the same mistake like me  (math.stackexchange.com/q/521299/801877).

@ArturoMagidin I think the main issue was that I had 2 questions to ask at once: why this overcounts what are the specific/exact instances to use the multiplication rule

@ArturoMagidin Maybe if I make the 2nd question a separate question on MSE, re-editing my 1st question to the original, would that work? Kindly let me know. Forgive me, it's my 1st time using MSE.

@ThomasAndrews Sorry I think you're comment has some typos. I guess it doesn't matter though since you already rewrote this comment more in-depth as an answer :) Thank you so much for that!

You should never change the question after you have received an answer. At the very least, it means that people who come later will believe the person who answered your question completely missed the point... and will downvote a perfectly fine answer because it is not helpful for your new question... which didn't even exist when the answer was posted.

@ArturoMagidin Alright I just rollbacked the edits. Now I'll make a new question linking this one!

The product rule says that if $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n$ are sets, then the number of tuples $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ with $a_i\in A_i$ is equal to the product of the numher of elements in each $A_i.$ In short:
$$|A_1\times\cdots\times A_n|=|A_1|\cdot\cdots\cdot |A_n|$$
In reality, we often call something the product rule when we are counting a set $S$ and find a function $f:A_1\times\cdots\times A_n\to S$ which is a bijection, and then $|S|=|A_1\times\cdot\times A_n|=|A_1|\cdots |A_n|.$
Such is the case in your example, and it is really a combination of two rules, the product rule and, for lack of memory, what I'll the bijection rule:

If there is a bijection $X\to Y,$ then $|X|=|Y|.$

When in doubt, always try to think of such a count of $S$ this way, and try to make sure you know what the $A_i,S,$ and $f$ are, and whether you know $f$ is a bijection.
In your argument, $A$ is the set of subsets $\{a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_m\}$ of $[n]$ of size $m,$ $B$ is the set of permutations on $[m],$ and $C$ is the set of functions $[n-m]\to [m].$
Now, $|A|=\binom nm, |B|=m!, |C|=m^{n-m},$ and your formula correctly counts $A\times B\times C.$
But your function $f$ is not a bijection.
Here, $S$ is the set of all onto functions $h:[n]\to [m].$
Your function takes a tuple $x=(M,\pi,g)$ where $M=\{a_1<\cdots<a_m\}\subseteq [n],$ $\pi$ is a permutation of $[m],$ and $g:[n-m]\to [m].$
You define a map $f_x:[n]\to[m]$ as follows.

Let $\{b_1<\cdots <b_{n-k}\}=[n]\setminus M.$
Define: $$f_x(k)=\begin{cases}\pi(i)&k=a_i\\
g(i)&k=b_i\end{cases}$$

This creates a map $A\times B\times C\to S$ sending $x\mapsto f_x.$
This map is onto, but it is not one-to-one. It is not a bijection,
So all we can really say is $|A||B||C|\geq |S|.$
It is worth noting what your function does count.
For example, we can say your function counts all pairs $$S_2=\{(M,h)\mid M\in B, h:[n]\to [m],h(M)=[m]\}.$$ The bijection is $x\mapsto (M,f_x),$ and we get $|S_2|=|A||B||C|.$ But, when $n>m$ and $h\in S,$ there will always be two or more $M$ with $(h,M)\in S_2.$ So $|S_2|\geq 2|S|.$

Thank you so much for your answer. I'll definitely first try to read up on functions again before I try to read this answer carefully since it's a bit overwhelming.

Yeah, if you are unaware of elementary ideas about functions it is hard to follow this answer. But the key is that, while you've shown there is an $x$ such that $F(x)=y,$ you haven't shown it is unique. In particular, if $n>m,$ and there is an onto function $h:[n]\to [m],$ there are multiple subsets $S\subset [n]$ of size $m$ such that $h(S)=[m].$ This means your function from the tuples is not one-to-one.

But ultimately, it is much more useful for clarifying your thoughts to understand that the product rule is the very simple statement about products of sets, $|A\times B|=|A|\cdot |B|.$ and that almost all errors that you think of as an error in using the product is really an error of thinking a function $A\times B\to C$ is a bijection which isn't. This is most common when finding the inverse, and you choose arbitrarily from several choices - this means that your map $A\times B\to C$ is not $1-1.$

Let's look at a small case, where $n=2$ and $m=1$. According to your formula, the number of surjections should be $\binom21\cdot 1!\cdot 1^{2-1}=2$. However, there is clearly only one surjection. This means your formula is overcounting, but why?
The problem is that when you choose a subset from the domain in $\binom nm$ ways, you are singling out that subsets as special. However, for any given function, there may be other subsets of the domain which were mapped bijectively to the range, which means those functions would be counted multiple times. In the previous example, we are counting surjections from a two element set, $\{a,b\}$, to a one element set, $\{c\}$. You could either choose the subset $\{a\}$ from the domain, and map it bijectively to $\{c\}$ in $1!$ way, and then map $\{b\}$ to $\{c\}$ arbitrarily, or you could do the opposite direction (map $\{b\}$ to $\{c\}$ bijectively, then map $\{a\}$ arbitrarily). However, both of these produce the same function, even though they are counted as different.

Thank you so much for your answer! I actually just edited the question to ask my real/main question, which is what are the exact conditions in which one can use the multiplication rule of combinatorics correctly. This particular problem was really just supposed to be an example of how one can use the multiplication rule wrong. I think many other people make similar mistakes too now that I see similar/same questions asked on this platform, where they use the exact same thought process! https://math.stackexchange.com/q/521299/801877

@BobMarley Don't rewrite your question after someone has written an extensive answer to your original question. If you want to ask a different question, start a new question.

@BobMarley Now that you have edited, I think your question cannot be answered on MSE. You ask, "Exactly when can I apply the rule of product?". To answer that, I essentially need to teach you a skill, which requires a whole lecture, and for you to do a couple dozen practice exercises. If you want help from MSE, find more combinatorics exercises which use rule of product, and ask about how the product rule applies to some specific cases.

@ThomasAndrews Very sorry about that. It's my first time using MSE. I think I'll just re-edit my question and then make a new question for the multiplication rule that links this one. Kindly let me know if that would that work.

@MikeEarnest I see what you're saying. However, the point of my question was to highlight a wrong usage of the multiplication rule, from which I hoped would've started a more detailed discussion of the specific/exact instances when the multiplication rule can be used, something that I personally see lacking in textbooks and intro combo courses. Maybe if I make a separate question for that, after reediting this question to the original one, that would work. Kindly let me know your thoughts. It's my first time using MSE, so I do apologize if my way of asking the questions wasn't as ideal.
